# Let $A=\{1,...,n\}.$ Show that there is a bijection of $P(A)$ with the cartesian product $X^n$ where $X$ is the two element set $X=\{0,1\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Wouldn't these two sets have the same cardinality?  If so, I am unsure of how to prove that two sets with the same cardinality have a bijective correspondence.

Comment: What is your definition of cardinality then?

Comment: Maybe I'm just a little confused.  Since P(A) is the power set of A, wouldn't the cardinality be 2^n and since X has two elements, shouldn't it's cardinality be 2^n as well?

Comment: You say :"I am unsure of how to prove that two sets with the same cardinality have a bijective correspondence", but isn't that the definition of having the same cardinality?

Comment: I think it's an iff thing.  I couldn't find the theorem in my book, it was just something I remembered.

Comment: By definition there must be a bijection between two sets with the same cardinality, but it is sometimes far from obvious what it is. You are asked to set out one of the possible bijections. Fortunately it is easy in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Define

$$f:P(A)\to \{0,1\}^n\;,\;\;f(X):=(i_1\;i_2\;\ldots i_n)\;,\;\;\text{where}$$

$$\text{for}\;\;1\le k\le n\;,\;\;\;i_k=\begin{cases}0\;,\;\;\text{if}\;\;k\notin X\\{}\\1\;,\;\;\text{if}\;\;k\in X\end{cases}$$

Now show $\;f\;$ is well defined between the given sets, and that it is a bijection.

Comment: Ah!  I see now.  Thank you so much!